# Your app is uploading users' contact list information without posting a privacy policy in both the designated field in the Play Developer Console

Tags: android, flutter

Your app is uploading users' contact list information without posting a privacy policy in both the designated field in the Play Developer Console and from within the Play distributed app itself.
But the application have the privacy policy link within the app and also updated with the privacy policy link in pp content. Still the app is removed/rejected why? and what needs to be done?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Comment: In the case of google you must put a modal or some kind of alert before requesting access permission from contacts, this is a google requirement and in this modal/alert you must explain why you need to access the contact list and what data you will use at the end of the import and why this is important for the application. Without alerting your application will not be published on the play developer and will be considered spyware according to their policy seen [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/11987217?hl=en).